# XSLT with XPath - Wrap children elements with new Parent

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Input:

```
<s:E1 ...>
    <s:E2 ...>
      <s:Child1 ...>
         <s:EChild1 ...>
         ...
         </s:EChild1 ...>
      </s:Child1 ...>
   </s:E2>
</s:E1 ...>
```

Desired Output is:

```
<s:E1 ...>
    <s:E2 ...>
      <s:XYZ>
          <s:Child1 ...>
             <s:EChild1 ...>
             ...
             </s:EChild1 ...>
          </s:Child1 ...>
      </s:XYZ>
   </s:E2>
</s:E1 ...>
```

I.E, I want wrap the *all children elements with their attributes and children* of `<s:E2>` in `<s:XYZ>`.

XSLT I came up with was:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" ...>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/> 
    <xsl:template match="//*:E2">
      <s:XYZ>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </s:XYZ>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is effectively generating an output where `<s:XYZ>` becomes `<s:E2>`, but not its direct child element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*:E2">
    <xsl:copy>
        <XYZ>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </XYZ>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```